# QRegularExpression: skip matching escaped tokens

Tags: qt, regex-negation, qregularexpression

I'm replacing a `QString` using `QRegularExpression` but I have a problem with escaped tokens.

For example: a `"{aaa}"` in the string should be replace with a `"bbb"` but a `"\{aaa}"` should be ignored and a `"{aaa}"` will be set (without the `"\"`).

eg:

> this is a test called {aaa}  -> this is a test called bbb
> this is a test called \{aaa} -> this is a test called {aaa}

I'm using

```
QString& replace(const QRegularExpression& re, const QString& after);
```

but I cannot find a way to skip an escaped match. I guess with a negative look-behind, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you came up with - `(?<!\\){aaa}` - will not match valid `{aaa}` that is preceded with a valid escaped backslash, `\\{aaa}`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLlc3N/1).

What you need is a regex that will account for these escaped backslashes:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K{aaa}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLlc3N/2).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a `\` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more occurrences of double backslash
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `{aaa}`  - a literal `{aaa}` substring.

In Qt, string literals may contain *escape sequences*, `\n` for a newline, `\r` for a carriage return, etc. To define a literal backslash (that is used to form *regex escapes*, regex operators, shorthand character classes), you need to double the backslash:

```
QRegularExpression re("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\K{aaa}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
QRegularExpression re(QString("(?<!\\\\)({aaa})")
```

I just missed that to match a backslash, 4 must be used.